# Save to file from command line operation and named it as [hostname].txt

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe, ipconfig

I am wondering if it is possible to save the following operation to a file while the name of the file is the host name:

I mean something like:

```
ipconfig /displaydns >hostname.txt
```

For example, in case my PC name is ehh then it will save to ehh.txt file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `%computername%` environment variable.

So, the command you need is `ipconfig /displaydns >%computername%.txt`
 You can find a more complete list of environmental variables in  Daniel Beck's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/284351/10165)

Comment: Great, works perfectly!!!